# Frechet spaces: topology induced by metric is the same as the topology induced by the family of seminorms

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff vector space whose topology is induced by a countable family of seminorms $\{\rho_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Prove that the metric 
>   $$d(x,y)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\frac{\rho_n(x-y)}{1+\rho_n(x-y)}.$$
>   induces the same topology.

Call $\mathcal{T}_1$ the topology generated by the seminorms. Then $U\in \mathcal{T}_1$ iff $U$ can be written as a union of sets of the form
$$\bigcap_{j\in J} B_{r_j}^{j}(x_j),$$
where the $x_j$'s are in $U$, $J$ is finite, and $B_{r_j}^{j}(x_j):=\{v\in X; \rho_j(v-x_j)<r_j\}.$

Call $\mathcal{T}_2$ the topology generated by the metric. So $U\in\mathcal{T}_2$ iff it can be written as a union of $\epsilon$-balls.

I also know that $X$ is Hausdorff, so if $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$, then there exist disjoint $U_1,U_2\in\mathcal{T}_1$ such that $x\in U_1$ and $y\in U_2$.

I would like to show that if $U\in\mathcal{T}_1$, then $U\in\mathcal{T}_2$ (and vice-versa). Any tips on how to get started?

Comment: Both topologies are translation-invariant, so you just need to check that both have the same neighbourhoods of $0$.

Comment: Would you mind to edit the title to replace "norm" by "metric"?

Comment: Done - thanks @Hanno

Comment: Note that the Hausdorff condition is equivalent to the following: for each $x\in X$ non-zero, there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\rho_n(x)\neq0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to check that each neighborhood $U_1$ of $0$ in $\mathcal T_1$ contains some open neighborhood $U_2$ of $0$ in $\mathcal T_2$, and vice versa.  This is equivalent to checking that the identity map $i:(X,\mathcal T_1)\to(X,\mathcal T_2)$ and its inverse $i^{-1}:(X,\mathcal T_2)\to(X,\mathcal T_1)$ are continuous at $0$.  Since the topologies $\mathcal T_1$ and $\mathcal T_2$ are translation invariant, and $i$ is linear, the result follows.

Now each topology has a nice basis, so you can restrict your attention to these basic open neighborhoods of $0$.

Comment: The first part is clear, but how does continuity follow from linearity and translation invariance?

Comment: Fix $x\in X$. Take a $\mathcal T_2$-open neighborhood $U_2$ of $x$, subtract $x$ to obtain $\mathcal T_2$-open neighborhood of $0$.  Then there is a $\mathcal T_1$-open neighborhood $U_1$ of $0$ with $U_1$ with $U_1\subset (U_2-x)$, and thus $U_1+x\subset U_2$.  Hence $i$ is continuous at $x$, and proving $i^{-1}$ is continuous at $x$ is obtained by switching subscripts.

Comment: Yes, that's clear - sorry, I thought you meant that continuity at $0$ follows from linearity and translation invariance

Comment: No problem.  If you need more help, let me know and I will edit.

Comment: Just checking I understand what I'm supposed to do. I'll start with one direction. Let's assume $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathcal{T}_2$. So for any $u\in U$, there's an $r_u$ such that $B_{r_u}(u)\in U$. In particular, this holds for $u=0$. I now need to show that, for any $x\in B_{r}(0)$ , there exists an $\epsilon_x>0$ and a $K_x\geq 0$ such that every element of $\{v; \rho_k(v-x)<\epsilon_x; \forall k\leq K\}$ satisfies $d(v,0)<r$.

Comment: It's simpler than that: Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $K\in N$, $\delta>0$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{1\leq k\leq K}\{v:p_k(v)<\delta\}\subset B_\varepsilon(0)$.

Comment: Thanks, @Aweygan. I've attempted to write a full proof continuity at $0$ (posted below as a separate answer), if you could have a quick look at it and let me know if anything's wrong I'd really appreciate it. I've accepted yours, of course

Answer (score 0):

(following on from Aweygan's answer)

Proof that $i$ is continuous:

Pick $M$ such that $2^{-M}\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Call $K$ the smallest non-negative integer such that $\rho_K(x)$ isn't equal to $0$ for all $x\in B_{\epsilon}(0)$. Such a $K$ certainly exists, from the Hausdorff condition.

\begin{align*}d(v,0)=&\sum_{n\geq 1}2^{-n}\frac{\rho_n(v)}{1+\rho_n(v)}\\
=&\sum_{n= 1}^M2^{-K}\frac{\rho_K(v)}{1+\rho_K(v)}+\sum_{n\geq M+1}2^{-n}\frac{\rho_n(v)}{1+\rho_n(v)}\\
\leq & \sum_{n= 1}^M2^{-K}\frac{\rho_K(v)}{1+\rho_K(v)}+\sum_{n\geq M+1}2^{-n}.\end{align*}
If $K>M$, then the first summation equals $0$ and the second one equals $2^{-M}\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, so $d(v,0)<\epsilon$ and we are done.

If $K\leq M$, then call $K^*$ the $K$ such that, for a given $v$, $\rho_K(v)$ is maximised (this maximum is attained as there is only a finite number of $K\leq M$). Since $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is a monotone increasing function for $x>0$, we have that
$$\sum_{n= 1}^M2^{-K}\frac{\rho_K(v)}{1+\rho_K(v)}\leq \frac{\rho_{K^*}(v)}{1+\rho_{K^*}(v)}\sum_{n= 1}^M2^{-K}\leq \frac{\rho_{K^*}(v)}{1+\rho_{K^*}(v)}.$$
If we choose $\delta$ such that $\frac{\delta}{1+\delta}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then substituting above we see that
$$d(v,0)\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$

Proof that $i^{-1}$ is continuous:

We need to show that, given $K$ and $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ such that $$B_{\delta}(0)\subset \bigcap_{k\leq K} \{v:\rho_k(v)<\epsilon\}.$$

For a given $v$, call $k^*$ the $k\leq K$ such that $\rho_k(v)$ is maximised. Then
$$2^{-k^*}\frac{\rho_{k^*}(v)}{1+\rho_{k^*}}\leq d(v,0).$$
Choosing $\delta$ such that
$$\frac{2^{k^*}\delta}{1-2^{k^*}\delta}<\epsilon$$
guarantees that $\rho_k(v)<\epsilon$ for all $k\leq K$.

Comment: Everything looks alright.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate you looking at it!